# I don't receive email notification from Azure Devops when someone use @mentions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-services

We normally receive email notifications when we use @mentions in workitems on Azure Devops and it is not working anymore for all of us. I checked on the notifications settings everything seems fine but still not working.

If you can help on that.

Thank you

Comment: Hello @KevinLu-MSFT i had only one answer which didn't solve my problem. what should i do in this case?

Comment: Maybe you can check some other possibilities: ['Not getting emails from subscriptions or notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

I used to copy the comment in the previous work item instead of typing @ and selecting the person, and then I found that no one would receive emails.

Although the format looks correct, it will not register as a real mention and will not send email notifications.

Like this, only the comment below will send me an email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

per documentation:
Note

Don't copy/paste @mention users from a previous comment. While the resulting formatting looks identical to a properly entered mention, it doesn't register as a true mention nor send an email notification.